# TO get the output of SQL select statement output into new line in Shell script

Tags: shell, sh

I was using this one to get the name of the tables older than 2019 but the output which i getting is coming as a single string.

```
#!/bin/sh
table_name=`isql -S$DB_SVR -U$DB_USR -P$DB_PWD -D$DB_DBN -b $DB_OPT -w5000 -b <<-! 
set nocount on
select name from SOX..sysobjects where crdate < '2019'
go
!`
table_name="$(echo -e "${table_name}" | tr -d '[[:space:]]')"
echo -e "table_name='${table_name}'"
```

OUTPUT:

```
table_name='ABCDEFGH'
```

Desired output:

```
table_name = 'A',
             'B',
             'c',
             'D',
```

what the changes should i made to get this output.

Comment: I would suggest adding the next line from the source itself. That means add char(10) or char(13) in your select statement. `select 'Hello' || chr(10) ||' world' from dual;` off course different platform expects different newline characters. same goes for `,`

Comment: @change198 i dont thnk adding of those will effect the output,thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you had showed us the original SQL contents of $table_name. However, assuming that the original SQL contents stored in $table_name is "A B C D E F G H", then you can replace the last two lines of your code with this one:

```
echo "$table_name" | perl -lpe "
BEGIN {\$SPACES=' ' x 8; }
s/\s+|$/'\n/g; s/^/'/mg;
s/$/,/mg; s/^'/\$SPACES'/mg;" | perl -pe '
s/=\s+/= /' | perl -pe '
s/^\s+/table = / if $. == 1' | head -4
```

and the result will be

```
table = 'A',
        'B',
        'C',
        'D',
```